# Shallow copy with vector

Tags: c++

Having trouble storing pointer objects in a vector.
I'm storing the values like this:

```
face.firstEdge = &edge
all_faces.push_back(face);
```

where `face.edge` is a pointer to an other object. 
My vector is declared like `std::vector<Face> all_faces;` and the struct is:

```
struct Face{
    Edge* firstEdge
}
```

When I later look through my elements they all have the same value which they shouln't have

```
for(int i = 0; i < all_faces.size(); i++){
    all_faces[i].firstEdge->vertex->x;
}
```

I know that the C++ compiler makes a shallow copy or something by default and everything points to the same address, I don't want this.

EDIT: Edge is a local variable `Edge edge = {};` declared and modified each time in a loop.

Comment: Show us your vector declaration!

Comment: Is face's copy constructor well defined? Could you show the definition of the type of face, the vector declaration, etc.

Comment: what scope has "edge" ?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that the C++ compiler makes a shallow copy or something by default and everything points to the same address

The most likely reason is that you are storing the address of a function local variable.

```
face.firstEdge = &edge;
```

If `edge` is a function local variable, and you call the function in a loop, it is most likely going to use the same stack frames and hence end up using same address.

If you are doing that, know that your program is subject to undefined behavior. You need to assign to `face.firstEdge` a pointer which points to memory allocated on the heap. Something like

```
face.firstEdge = new Edge(edge);
```

Comment: Be careful with memory management, you could easily get memory leaks. Use smart pointers. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared within a loop are constructed and destroyed every time it loops - they are variables on the stack. You can't save pointers to these, they become invalid when you leave the scope.

You need to allocate the variables on the heap - as R Rahu explained - using `new/new[]`, or smart pointers. If the objects don't hold resources, it may be better to store values, not pointers.

```
std::vector< int* > vec;
    //(...)
    {
        int outside_loop = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            int inside_loop = 0; //constructed
            outside_loop = 0; //new assignment, still refering to the same variable
            int* heap_var = new int(0); //on heap

            vec.push_back(&inside_loop);
            vec.push_back(&outside_loop);
            vec.push_back(heap_var); //good, variable is on heap   
        }//inside_loop destroyed

        //vec[0], vec[3] point to variables that no longer exist, they are destroyed at the end of the loop
        //vec[1] == vec[4] both point to outside_loop, still on stack
        //vec[2], vec[5] good, each points to a unique variable on heap, which isn't destroyed until delete is called
    }//outside_loop is destroyed

//vec[1], vec[4] are now invalid, outside_loop was destroyed
```

I tested the code above, and `vec[0] & vec[3]` have the same address. This is because `inside_loop` in the loop is created in the same position on the stack. Also, it contains an initialized value of 0, because an `inside_loop` was previously initialized there and the address has not been used; this is probably why you see them in your code as having the same value - it's the same address in memory, holding the value of whatever the last variable had. This address will be used when new variables are pushed onto the stack. Permanent (lvalue) references and pointers to stack variables are a big "No No".